# Chrome on Ubuntu - Unable to open X display and unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having numerous issues getting chromedriver/Google Chrome to work on ubuntu. While I've gotten it to work sporadically, it has never worked consistently. This is an EC2 instance, running a Python script.

Chrome version is `91.0.4472.114` and chromedriver version is `91.0.4472.101`

However, when I type google-chrome in the terminal, I get:

```
[1799:1799:0620/033825.232832:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1402)] Unable to open X display.
```

This is even after installing xvfb : `sudo apt-get install -y xvfb`

Maybe that's causing my script to fail?  Here's my script, a simple web scraper so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import string
import json
import geocoder
import mapbox
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt
import re
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = Options()
#Set up web driver and base URL
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')



#Set base url (SAN FRANCISCO)
base_url = 'https://www.bandsintown.com/?place_id=ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo&page='#san francisco
#base_url = 'https://www.bandsintown.com/?place_id=ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g&page='


events = []
eventContainerBucket = []

for i in range(1,2):
    
    #cycle through pages in range
    driver.get(base_url + str(i))
    pageURL = base_url + str(i)
    print(pageURL)
    # get events links
    event_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class^=_3buUBPWBhUz9KBQqgXm-gf] a[class^=_3UX9sLQPbNUbfbaigy35li]')
    # collect href attribute of events in even_list
    events.extend(list(event.get_attribute("href") for event in event_list))

print ("total events: ", (len(events)))


# iterate through all events and open them.
item = {}
allEvents = []
for event in events:

    driver.get(event)
    currentUrl = driver.current_url
    print(currentUrl)
    try:
        currentRequest = requests.get(currentUrl)
        #print currentRequest.status_code
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)
        continue
```

So, it runs the script but gets hung up on the printing of the URLs, and I've gotten this error, which is of course unhelpful:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "BandsintownWebScraper.py", line 106, in <module>

    currentUrl = driver.current_url

  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 669, in current_url

    return self.execute(Command.GET_CURRENT_URL)['value']

  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 319, in execute

    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)

  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute

    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)

  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 397, in _request

    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 66, in request

    **urlopen_kw)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 87, in request_encode_url

    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 322, in urlopen

    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen

    chunked=chunked)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request

    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1373, in getresponse

    response.begin()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 311, in begin

    version, status, reason = self._read_status()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 272, in _read_status

    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto

    return self._sock.recv_into(b)

KeyboardInterrupt
```

The funny thing is, this script has worked in the past, but it fails to work consistently. It's failing when looping through the URLs.

UPDATE:

Tried again to run script today, here's the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Comment: Is there an error if you don't do CTRL-C? If so, can you post the full traceback? Thanks.

Comment: Which  ubuntu? 20.04? Also how did you install  your chrome driver exactly? In other words, how to reproduce your issue, step by step.

Comment: error message posted.